# How to prove $V(5x^2+6xy+2y^2-2yz-z^2)$ is empty

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algebraic-geometry

Let $V/\mathbb{Q}$ be the projective variety $V:5x^2+6xy+2y^2=2yz+z^2$. I want to prove $V(\mathbb{Q})$ is empty. Given $[x,y,z]$ in $V$, WLOG assume $x,y,z\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $\gcd(x,y,z)=1$. $x^2-z^2=0\bmod 2$, so either $x=z=0$ mod 2 or $x=z=1\bmod 2$. In the first case I can show $2\mid y$, which contradicts $\gcd(x,y,z)=1$. But I don't know how to deal with the second case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rewrite everything as
$$3(x+y)^2+2x^2=(y+z)^2$$
looking at this modulo $3$, you can show that $3$ divides both $x$ and $(y+z)$ (an idea to show this: squares modulo $3$ are just $0,1$, and $3$ is a prime). In particular $9$ divides both $x^2$ and $(y+z)^2$.

But now, looking this modulo $9$, you have
$$(x+y)^2 \equiv 0 \mod{9}$$
hence $3$ divides $(x+y)$ as well.

But this contradicts the fact that $x,y,z$ are coprime.

Comment: I am conscious that I missed some details. If you need some, you just have to ask.